# How to create a joint probability table from existing conditioinal probability tables? (CPTs)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, probability, bayesian, bayesian-networks, probability-theory

I have the following tables ,with the dependencies below :

[image]

And I want to create the joint-probability table for `P(M,P,W,B)` , which looks like this (and of course ,you can assume that the below table **is not given to me** , it is taken from the answer for this question) :

[image]

Can someone please explain how can I create the joint probability table for `P(M,P,W,B)` ?

Much appreciate

Comment: That's homework? Then add the homework tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joint probability for *P(M,P,W,B)* is simply the product of the entries of the other tables. This is from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_network#Factorization_definition):

*X* is a Bayesian network with respect to *G* if its joint probability density function (with respect to a product measure) can be written as a product of the individual density functions, conditional on their parent variables:

[image: p (x) = \prod_{v \in V} p \big(x_v \,\big|\, x_{\operatorname{pa}(v)} \big)]

where *pa(v)* is the set of parents of *v* (i.e. those vertices pointing directly to *v* via a single edge).